# Post-build powershell script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, post-build-event, building

I have the following post-build event:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell -file "$(SolutionDir)Obfuscation\_obfuscate.ps1" "$(SolutionDir)" "$(ProjectDir)"
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

and PS script beginning with:

```
param
(   
    [string]$slnDir,
    [string]$projectDir
)
```

when MSBuild trys to run it, my first parameter `"$(SolutionDir)"` is splitted in two parameters because the solution path contains a space character: `D:\Projects\Dion2 Mercurial\repo\Dion2Web\`. So my script receives `D:\Projects\Dion2` as the first parameter and `Mercurial\repo\Dion2Web\` as the second one.

What is the correct way to send those parameters to the script file?

Note: such post-build scripts works fine when script has only one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Try adjusting your post build event to use the following:

```
powershell -file "$(SolutionDir)Obfuscation\_obfuscate.ps1" -slnDir '$(SolutionDir)' -projectDir '$(ProjectDir)'
```

Comment: You can add the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` parameter if you don't want to change the execution policy permanently.